# Trigger Jenkins Job from shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-shared-libraries

This is what I have in my shared library file

```
build job: 'Job Name',
          parameters:
          [
               string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', value: 'sit'),
               string(name: 'param1', value: 'value1' )
          ]
```

It is failing with below error :

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: build.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[job:**********, parameters:[@string(name=ENVIRONMENT,value=sit), ...]]]
Possible solutions: call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), wait(long), main([Ljava.lang.String;), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Any help here?

Answer (score 1):

**Library classes cannot directly call steps such as sh or git**. They can however implement methods, outside of the scope of an enclosing class, which in turn invoke Pipeline steps, for example:

```
// src/org/foo/Zot.groovy
package org.foo;

def checkOutFrom(repo) {
  git url: "git@github.com:jenkinsci/${repo}"
}

return this
```

Which can then be called from a Scripted Pipeline:

```
def z = new org.foo.Zot()
z.checkOutFrom(repo)
```

This approach has limitations; for example, it prevents the declaration of a superclass.

Alternately, a set of steps can be passed explicitly using this to a library class, in a constructor, or just one method:

```
package org.foo
class Utilities implements Serializable {
  def steps
  Utilities(steps) {this.steps = steps}
  def mvn(args) {
    steps.sh "${steps.tool 'Maven'}/bin/mvn -o ${args}"
  }
}
```

When saving state on classes, such as above, the class must implement the Serializable interface. This ensures that a Pipeline using the class, as seen in the example below, can properly suspend and resume in Jenkins.

```
@Library('utils') import org.foo.Utilities
def utils = new Utilities(this)
node {
  utils.mvn 'clean package'
}
```

If the library needs to access global variables, such as env, those should be explicitly passed into the library classes, or methods, in a similar manner.

Instead of passing numerous variables from the Scripted Pipeline into a library,

```
package org.foo
class Utilities {
  static def mvn(script, args) {
    script.sh "${script.tool 'Maven'}/bin/mvn -s ${script.env.HOME}/jenkins.xml -o ${args}"
  }
}
```

The above example shows the script being passed in to one static method, invoked from a Scripted Pipeline as follows:

```
@Library('utils') import static org.foo.Utilities.*
node {
  mvn this, 'clean package'
}
```

For more info see jenkins shared library documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `propagate` and `wait` like below:

```
build job: 'Job Name', parameters: [ string(name: 'ENVIRONMENT', value: 'sit'), string(name: 'param1', value: 'value1' ) ],propagate: true, wait: true
```

Comment: tried above changes, but getting the same error as before.

Comment: and I literally copied the same text as generated by Snippet Generator and even that threw the same error!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I figured out the problem.

One of the shared file name was build.groovy which was causing conflicts with build pipeline step. Renamed the file and that fixed the issue.